# Is there any optimization algorithm to solve this?

Tags: optimization

I am trying to solve this problem:

**About offers**

```
- There are 3 offers with 3 costs. C = [10,20,30]

- And 3 quotas (availability of the offers). Q = [5,10,15]
```

**About people**

```
- There is a matrix of 5 people with profits calculated for each offer.

  P = [[10,20,50],[20,60,10],[30,50,15],[60,40,50],[10,25,50]]
```

---

**The problem**:

We can distribute maximum 5 offers worth $10, 10 offers worth $20 and 15 offers worth $30. **I need to assign only one offer for one person.** My total budget is $700. I need to assign offers to people in a way such that, I get the maximum profit.

** Is there any optimization algorithm that I can use to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can solve this with integer programming.

For example by using [CPLEX](https://www.ibm.com/products/ilog-cplex-optimization-studio). There is a free edition for academic use, see [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=6b05a456-6905-4f21-afc0-aea3c4ee66ca&ps=25). The documentation is available online [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.studio.help/Optimization_Studio/topics/COS_home.html).

Written in OPL (the modeling language that comes with CPLEX) your optimization problem could look like this:range offers = 1..3;

```
range people = 1..5;
int C[offers] = [10,20,30];
int Q[offers] = [5,10,15];
int P[people][offers] = [[10,20,50],[20,60,10],[30,50,15],[60,40,50],[10,25,50]];

int budget = 700;

dvar boolean assign[p in people][o in offers];  // 1 if offer o is assigned to person p
dvar int+ quantity[p in people][o in offers];   // how much of offer o is shipped to person p
dexpr int profit = sum(p in people, o in offers) quantity[p][o] * P[p][o];

// Maximize the profit
maximize profit;

subject to {
  // Assign at most one offer to each person
  forall (p in people)
    sum(o in offers) assign[p][o] <= 1;
  // Respect the quota
  forall (o in offers)
    sum(p in people) quantity[p][o] <= Q[o];
  // Respect the budget limit
  sum(o in offers) C[o] * sum(p in people) quantity[p][o] <= budget;
  // The quantity can only be >0 if the "assign" variable is 1.
  forall(o in offers, p in people)
    quantity[p][o] <= C[o] * assign[p][o];
}

// Dump the results. This would not be necessary if you solved the problem
// in the IDE that ships with CPLEX.
execute {
  for (var p in people) {
    for (var o in offers) {
      if (quantity[p][o] > 0) {
        writeln("Ship " + quantity[p][o] + " of offer " + o + " to " + p);
      }
    }
  }
  writeln("Total profit: " + profit);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate your contribution.